# Accessing Object returned from AsyncTask NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I was having some problem when trying to access the object returned from doInBackground() in Android. When my button onClick, it will execute the doInBackground() in **GetEventDetailAsyncTask** class:

```
viewDtlEventBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //eventModel.setEventID(String.valueOf(eventIDTV.getText()));
            new GetEventDetailAsyncTask(new GetEventDetailAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                public void onFinish() {
                    // Passing whole object with value into another activity
                    Intent eventDtlIntent = new Intent(context, EventDetailMain.class);
                    eventDtlIntent.putExtra("eventObj", eventModel);
                    eventDtlIntent.putExtra("eventCommentObj", eventCommentModel);
                    context.startActivity(eventDtlIntent);
                }
            }).execute(String.valueOf(eventIDTV.getText()));
        }
    });
```

Then in my **GetEventDetailAsyncTask** class, it will execute the method in **EventController** class which return an EventComment object:

```
public class GetEventDetailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, EventComment> {
EventController eventCtrl = new EventController();
Context context;
EventComment comment = new EventComment();

public interface OnRoutineFinished { // interface
    void onFinish();
}

private OnRoutineFinished mCallbacks;

public GetEventDetailAsyncTask(OnRoutineFinished callback) { // constructor with
                                                    // interface
    mCallbacks = callback;
}

public GetEventDetailAsyncTask() {
} // empty constructor to maintain compatibility

public GetEventDetailAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        //eventCtrl.getEventDetailByID(params[0]);
        eventCtrl.getEventCommentByID(params[0]);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(EventComment result) {
    comment = result;
    if (mCallbacks != null)
        mCallbacks.onFinish(); // call interface on finish
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
}
```

}

**EventController class**

```
public EventComment getEventCommentByID(String eventID) throws JSONException {
    EventComment eventCommentModel = new EventComment();
    String page;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(ENeighbourhoodActivity.URL
                + "/EventServlet?action=GetCommentById&eventID=" + eventID
                + "");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        page = "{\'EventComment\':" + responseString + "}";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("EventComment");
            int length = jsonArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String commentBy = attribute.getString("commentBy");
                String commentDate = attribute.getString("commentDate");
                String commentTime = attribute.getString("commentTime");
                String commentDesc = attribute.getString("commentDesc");
                eventCommentModel.setCommentBy(commentBy);
                eventCommentModel.setCommentDate(commentDate);
                eventCommentModel.setCommentTime(commentTime);
                eventCommentModel.setCommentDesc(commentDesc);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return eventCommentModel;
}
```

However, when my button is onClick and pass the eventComment object as parameter to **EventChat** class, it was null and I am getting NullPointerException when trying to access the object itself.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug your code, See if `getEventDetailByID` return something

Comment: Yeah, getEvenyCommentByID did returned something. Just that when it goes from button onclick, it's null.

Comment: @BlazeTama The current problem is it could not get the object returned from AsyncTask class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Theres something fishy on this code :

```
try {
    eventCtrl.getEventDetailByID(params[0]);
    eventCtrl.getEventCommentByID(params[0]);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
```

Take a closer look, you called `eventCtrl.getEventDetailByID(params[0]);` but **dont** save what its returned.

You need to create an instance of `EventComment` and use it :

```
myEvenComment = eventCtrl.getEventCommentByID(params[0]);
```